# Connected App with Custom Endpoint

Tags: connected-apps, create-records

I'm not sure how to ask this question. We have a custom endpoint that handles the creation of leads from external partners. We recently added a partner and they are using a connected app. I didn't think of the implications, and now they are creating leads without it running through our endpoint.

Is there a way to route lead creation from a connected app to a custom class?

Comment: They are calling your APEX class, but getting access token from some other connected app?

Comment: I think I may have had a panic driven bone-head moment. Just having a connected app is not enough to post to SF, is it? The vendor would still need to post to an endpoint. If we gave them permissions, they could be posting to the generic endpoint rather than our custom endpoint. That seems to be the most likely scenario. So I guess we need to just update the endpoint they are pointed to?